# UINavigationBar tint color flashing in iOS 4

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationbar

The app I'm working on has a custom nab bar but supports iOS 4.2-iOS 5, so I need to set the UINavigationBar background and tint in this old school way in my app delegate.

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (UINavigationBarCategory)

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    self.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:42.0/255.0 
                                     green:164.0/255.0 
                                      blue:182.0/255.0
                                     alpha:1.0];
    UIImage *img  = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar_bg.png"];
    [img drawInRect:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 
                               self.frame.size.width, 
                               self.frame.size.height)];
}
@end
```

This works for the most part, but I noticed when the app is first starting, the UIBarButtonItems flash the default navigation bar color for a second before they correct themselves and change color to match the navigation bar. Interestingly, the navigation bar itself uses the background image correctly from the get-go.

To be clear, I'm using setBackgroundImage for UINavigationBar on iOS 5 devices which works as expected so the flash is only in iOS 4.

Anyone have any insight on why this would happen and/or how to fix it?

Comment: At what point in the application's lifecycle do you call the class with the code referenced, is it in viewDidLoad ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bar button items are the wrong color? You can manually set their tint color in viewDidLoad: to the tint color

```
 navigationBar.rightBarButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor ...]
```

if you're using a nib file. Otherwise you can do the same thing in loadView: . Either way this code will get executed as part of the initial draw loop so you'll have the proper color without any flashing.

Also for future reference, it's technically incorrect to override a method inside a category. (The latest version of Xcode, 4.3, will give you a warning about this). You should either properly subclass UINavigationBar or do "method swizzling". But that's pretty tough so don't worry about it right now :)

Comment: This ended up being the solution- just manually setting the navigation bar tint color of the first view controller that loads. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you call the class with the code referenced in viewDidLoad try moving it to awakeFromNib